# Kotlin: How to read MutableLiveData in Background

Tags: android, kotlin

I created `MutableLiveData<Int>` in order to keep tracking step count.

```
  companion object {
        var todayTotalStepCount: MutableLiveData<Int>? = MutableLiveData()
    }
```

And I use `ForegroundService` to make `SensorManager` keep working in background or even when app is off.

In `Service()` class, I use `NotificationManager` and I want this notification keep noticing mutable step count.

```
    private fun secondNoti(stepCount: Int?) {
        Log.d("결과1", "$todayTotalStepCount")
        Log.d("결과2", "$stepCount")


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            val CHANNEL_ID = "my_app"
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "MyApp", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            (getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).createNotificationChannel(
                channel
            )
            val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
                .setContentTitle("${todayTotalStepCount?.value} 걸음")
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.main_color))
                .build()
            startForeground(1, notification)
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see above, I tried to show this value as title with below line.

```
.setContentTitle("${todayTotalStepCount?.value} 걸음")
```

However It shows `null`.

I print `todayTotalStepCount` on log, and it says:

```
 androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData@759014c
```

I tried to read this MutableLiveData value by using `observe`.

```
  todayTotalStepCount?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { value ->
        receivedStep = value
    }
```

But It can't define `viewLifecycleOwner`.

[image]

So My question is how can I read this MutableLiveData value in Notification which runs on background as separate function.

I'm a newbie in Kotlin, So please help me with detail code.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `observeForever` to observe a LiveData without a LifecycleOwner, and it’s your responsibility to cancel the observation when done. You could also use LifecycleService instead of Service, so it is a LifecycleOwner. But since observing happens on the main thread, and Services don’t run on the main thread, I don’t know exactly how it will behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use global static variable for this type of data, because it's not being shared between different app instance, and easy to be reseted to null if the app is cleared

My suggestion is define your custom BroadcastReceiver to transfer data between your Service and the main app, which is well-documented in [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts)

**1/ Define your own BroadcastReceiver class**

`class CurrentStepCountReceiver : BroadcastReceiver`

**2/ Register your receiver in Manifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".CurrentStepCountReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="your.package.name.currentstepcountreceiver" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**3/ Do your logic in `onReceived()` in `CurrentStepCountReceiver`**

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    // Retrieve the step count via intent data
    // Show your notification here
}
```

**4/ When your `ForegroundService` get new sensor data, pass the data to the `Intent` and use `sendBroadcast` to wake up any registered receiver, which is now your code inside `onReceived`**

```
Intent().also { intent ->
    intent.setAction("your.package.name.currentstepcountreceiver")
    intent.putExtra("step_count", newStepCount)
    sendBroadcast(intent)
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks. so Recap: I have `Service` class to run `SensorManager` on background and if step count sensor detects, I will send this data by using Intent to `BroadcastReceiver` and there `NotificationManager` will work. And I will send this data to `Activity`. -> Is that correct?

Comment: The stanalone receiver should just show the notification because it can work when app is close. If you want the `Activity` to reveices the event too, you have to write another BroadcastReceiver class inside the Activity, and `registerBroadcast` - with the same IntentFilter name - in onCreate, unregister onDestroy, so it is scoped into the activity lifecycle